# Pandas dataframe to list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Dataframe which looks like below. It is containing information about plans, activities and items.
Each plan is including multiple activities, and each activity is including multiple items.

```
| plan_id | plan_name | activity_id | activity_name | item_id | item_name |
| --------| --------- |------------ |-------------- |-------- |---------- |
| 1       | plan1     | 1           | activity1     | 1       | item1     |
| 1       | plan1     | 2           | activity2     | 3       | item3     |
| 2       | plan2     | 1           | activity1     | 1       | item1     |
```

I want to convert it to list of dicts

```
[
    {
        'plan_id':1,
        'plan_name':plan1,
        activities:
        [
            {
                activity_id: 1,
                activity_name: 'activity1'
                items:
                [
                    {
                        'item_id:1,
                        'item_name':'item1'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                activity_id: 2,
                activity_name: 'activity2'
                items:
                [
                    {
                        'item_id:3,
                        'item_name':'item3'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'plan_id':2,
        'plan_name':plan2,
        activities:
        [
            {
                activity_id: 1,
                activity_name: 'activity1'
                items:
                [
                    {
                        'item_id:1,
                        'item_name':'item1'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is there any fast way to do this?

**UPDATE**

I found that one solution is to create 3 dataframes - with items, activities and plans and loop over them like this:

```
plans_dict = plans_df.to_dict('records')
for plan in plans_dict:
    plan['activities'] = activities_df[activities_df['id']==plan['id']].to_dict('records')
    for activity in plan['activities']:
        activity['items'] = items_df[items_df['activity_id']==activity['activity_id']].to_dict('records')
```

I am not sure if it is the fastest solution.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Might be helpful check out [`DataFrame.to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Comment: but that's not what the OP wants: they want to structure hierarchically after grouping by certain keys. Neither `.to_json()` nor `.to_dict()` will achieve that readily. Some grouping needs to occur. Also, `.to_json()` just produces a string of the `.to_dict()` output. The OP wants a `dict`, not a `str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```py
def group_dict(df, name, keys):
    gkeys = [k for k in df.columns if k not in keys]
    r = df.groupby(gkeys)[keys].apply(pd.DataFrame.to_dict, orient='records')
    return r.to_frame(name).reset_index()

def to_grouped_dicts(df):
    df1 = group_dict(df, 'items', ['item_id', 'item_name'])
    df2 = group_dict(df1, 'activities', ['activity_id', 'activity_name', 'items'])
    return df2.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Then:

```py
>>> to_grouped_dicts(df)
[{'plan_id': 1,
  'plan_name': 'plan1',
  'activities': [{'activity_id': 1,
    'activity_name': 'activity1',
    'items': [{'item_id': 1, 'item_name': 'item1'}]},
   {'activity_id': 2,
    'activity_name': 'activity2',
    'items': [{'item_id': 3, 'item_name': 'item3'}]}]},
 {'plan_id': 2,
  'plan_name': 'plan2',
  'activities': [{'activity_id': 1,
    'activity_name': 'activity1',
    'items': [{'item_id': 1, 'item_name': 'item1'}]}]}]
```

## Explanation

The idea is to collect the list of dicts for a given group. For example, the first line:

```py
df1 = group_dict(df, 'items', ['item_id', 'item_name'])
```

does a `df.groupby('plan_id', 'plan_name', 'activity_id', 'activity_name')`; for each such group, it looks at the desired keys (`['item_id', 'item_name']`) and makes a list of dicts with that content, into a new column called `'items'`:

```py
print(df1)
   plan_id plan_name  activity_id activity_name  \
0        1     plan1            1     activity1   
1        1     plan1            2     activity2   
2        2     plan2            1     activity1   

                                    items  
0  [{'item_id': 1, 'item_name': 'item1'}]  
1  [{'item_id': 3, 'item_name': 'item3'}]  
2  [{'item_id': 1, 'item_name': 'item1'}]
```

Then we apply the same logic for the "next level up" (to make a column `'activities'`).

## Speed

For testing, here is a way to build an arbitrary size `df` like the example:

```py
n = 100_000
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'plan_id': np.random.randint(0, 20, size=n),
    'activity_id': np.random.randint(0, 20, size=n),
    'item_id': np.random.randint(0, 20, size=n),    
})
df = df.assign(**{
    k.replace('_id', '_name'): k.replace('_id', '_') + v
    for k, v in df.astype(str).items()
})
```

On such a 100K `df`, the time is:

```py
%timeit to_grouped_dicts(df)
# 314 ms ± 940 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

In this case, it is in fact a bit faster than a single and simple `.to_dict()`:

```py
%timeit df.to_dict(orient='records')
# 509 ms ± 579 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The speed ratio depends on how repeated the various groups are. `.to_dict()` doesn't do any grouping, so it has to spit out every single cell of every single row.  If there is less grouping occurring, then `to_grouped_dicts()` can be slower than `.to_dict()`.